# mediaelement.js not playing video in IE 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, mediaelement.js

I just started using mediaelement.js a few days ago.

Everything works so far except that IE9 doesn't show any videos (natively) even though the sound plays fine. With Flash it works fine.

The video element seems to disappear (width and height = 0) after the success callback has run. If I manually change the size it's just black.

I tried playing the demo video from mediaelementjs.com but the video was black as well.

I tried setting the size manually after success callback ( [mediaelement.js: Local Flash playback shows black video with sound unless shown full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182682/mediaelement-js-local-flash-playback-shows-black-video-with-sound-unless-shown) ). This displays the video element but it's still only black. The sound still plays.

In [Mediaelement.js malfunction in IE, no flashback works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190831/mediaelement-js-malfunction-in-ie-no-flashback-works) I found a possible solution using an undocumented property.

```
/*@cc_on
@if (@_jscript_version == 9)
    mode: 'shim',
@end
@*/
```

This forces IE to use flash but I'm not that comfortable using it in a productive environment.

Does anyone have a better solution?

**UPDATE:** I just tested on another computer with the same OS and browser (Windows 7, IE 9.0.8112) and there the video on mediaelementjs.com plays fine. Could it have something to do with my installation? I normally never use IE and haven't changed anything...

Comment: May I know what's your machine configuration and version of Mediaelementjs?

Comment: It's the newest version of Mediaelementjs (2.9.1) on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit with IE 9.0.8112. On my local web server (XAMPP 1.7.7 / Apache 2.2.21 / PHP 5.5.16) the video area doesn't show up at all but I can see the progress bar. Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, to run the HTML5 video on IE9, your server should configure with MIME-Type (.mp4). You have to add manually this configuration type into server config file. Check the link for more details http://drupal.org/node/1369136

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that. The demo on mediaelementjs.com also sends the correct mime type but it just won't display in IE.

Comment: oh, R u facing this problem for any videos or any particular video? Have u tried to open mediaelementjs.com site and test there video is working or not in your machine? If there is no problem with HTML5 online video in IE9, then I think it is totally depends on your server mis-configuration. Because with the same version of mediaelementjs my videos are working fine in IE9 and all the other browsers.

Comment: As I wrote in the question the demo video also doesn't work. I'm not behind a proxy, I haven't installed any plugins and don't think I changed any options of IE. I've tried a few files but none of them worked. Does the demo work for you? Do you have an URL to your videos so I could try if they work for me?

Comment: Only displays white for me apart from the loading indicator. I tried putting the site in exceptions lists for security, cookies etc. but nothing helped.

Comment: I have removed the link for some privacy issue, but I think something block your video from buffering. I don't have any idea about that, it's not a code related issue, so I cant help, it may be websense, proxy or something else. It's my limitation here. I can't check the configuration. So sorry, I am closing this conversation here. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for helping anyway. I'll simply use flash for IE.